# How do I find the screen shot of a video frame, at what second of the video it appears?

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing

I have old (no deterioration) and long (around 12 hours) television recordings and I want to divide them into programs. In these recordings, the same image appears before each program. Although I don't know much, I created a code like this using python and cv2 library.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
video = cv2.VideoCapture("Channel X 2005.01.01 22.15.mp4")
img = cv2.imread("channelxcapture.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
file = open("time.txt", "w")
threshold = 0.8 
skip = 10
count = 0 
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret: 
        break
    count += 1 
    if count % skip != 0: 
        continue 
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(frame, img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result) 
    time = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) 
    print(time/1000) 
    print(max_val) 
    if max_val > threshold: 
        file.write(str(time) + "\n")


file.close() 
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I couldn't get the result I wanted from histogram and pixel comparison, but I got what I wanted without template comparison, but it is very slow.

Which comparison method should I use?
Is this method correct for my purpose or should I try something else?
Is there another library or program that will make it faster and more consistent?
How can I speed up the process?

Edit:The picture in question appears for about a second. The minimum program length is ten minutes.

Edit 2: I made equals by mistake in frame skipping, I changed it to unequal.

Comment: Currently you are skipping every 10th frame. The other 9 frames are examined. What about examining only every 10th frame and skipping the other 9? How long is the program dividing image a shown? How long is the minimal length of each program?

Comment: @Markus I couldn't do well with the frame jump thing. Considering that the picture is usually shown for about one second, a jump can actually be made according to the frame rate of the video. It currently takes ten times the video length in the template system. If you say how many seconds the frame I'm looking for is displayed, as I said above, it is shown for one second. Although there are also short programs in the recording, a minimum of ten minutes varies from recording to recording.